# If I delete 92 GB of photos on my Mac Mini will it be erased from iCloud?

Tags: icloud, photos

I'm kinda new in Apple ecosystem and I'm currently moving personal stuff from Google to Apple. I have 92 GB of photos and videos that I've downloaded from Google Takeout that I put in Apple Photos through the import option. Now that the whole process has finished, if I manually delete that content, will it be erased from Apple Photos?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends.  What do you have synced with iCloud?

Comment: I have iCloud with Photos toggled on on my Mac.